# how to verify if an input read from console is a file name or a file full path

Tags: c#, xml, directory, console-application, filepath

I have a console application in C# and I would like to load an xml file, the path to the file is provided via console.readline(). But, I would like to load the file from the provided path but if the user only provides the name of the file I would like to search for it in the local folder from where the application is running. How can I know when I get only a file name as an input or a file full path. 
I managed that using:  `var isFileNameOnly = ((xmlFilePath.IndexOf("\\")) == -1);`

But this ugly and probably very buggy.

Full code:

```
        var xmlFilePath = Console.ReadLine();
        var xmlFile = new XmlDocument();

        var isFileNameOnly = ((xmlFilePath.IndexOf("\\")) == -1);
        try
        {
            if (isFileNameOnly)
            {
                xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, xmlFilePath);
            }

            xmlFile.Load(xmlFilePath);

        }
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file name entered by user actually exists using Exists() method. If it returns true load the file.

```
File.Exists(xmlFilePath)
```

Also XmlDocument.Load() if provided only file name will try to find the file in the BaseDirectory itself. So if file.Exists() return true you can assume XmlDocument.Load will load it whether it is local or absolute path.

Comment: yeah, but, if I try to execute the app from command line (cmd), the XmlDocument.Load() will try to find the file not in BaseDirectory, but in C:\user\myuser\ so I have to know if it's a file so I can append the BaseDirectory Path to the file. I think will appent the base directory and then verify if ít's exists. thx

Answer (score 0):

This will return false:

```
bool isFolder = Path.IsPathRooted(@"Text.txt");
```

This will return true:

```
bool isFolder = Path.IsPathRooted(@"C:\Text");
```

Comment: This won't work if the user specifies a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the same that I would have chosen. If the param doesn't contain any directory delimiter char, then it must be a filename only. Maybe it would be a little more elegant if you did it like this:

```
bool isFileNameOnly = !xmlFilePath.Contains(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString());
```